# How can i manipulate results of a results of a related table in a one-to-many hive table

Tags: sql, hive

I have data that looks something like this:

Accounts

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Account_Sales

| account_id | sale_location | sale_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ONLINE | BIG |
| 1 | IN_STORE | BIG |
| 2 | IN_STORE | BIG |
| 3 | IN_STORE | SMALL |
| 1 | ONLINE | SMALL |
| 3 | ONLINE | SMALL |

I am trying to store this data in a more convenient way for quick lookup in something like this:

| account_id | has_big_online_sale | has_big_in_store_sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | true |
| 2 | false | true |
| 3 | false | false |

I am running into some issues knowing where to start here. I can easily join Account and Account_Sales tables, but populating the convenience table based on values of the join is throwing me for a loop. Anyone have suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when sale_location = 'online' and sale_type = 'big' then 1 else 0 end) as has_big_online,
       max(case when sale_location = 'in_store' and sale_type = 'big' then 1 else 0 end) as has_big_online,
from t
group by id;
```

Note:  the behavior of booleans depends on the version of Hive, so this just uses a 1/0 flag for the column.